# Syntax Error - Been trying to figure this out all day

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Users\Dana\Local Sites\true-crime-community\app\public\wp-content\themes\makua\page.php on line 65

But I cant figure out whats wrong or how to fix it. No matter what I do. Could someone please explain the error and how to fix it? I'm in the process of learning to code.

```
<?php

    get_header();


  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); ?>

  <div class="page-banner">
    <div class="page-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/ocean.jpg') ?>);"></div>
    <div class="page-banner__content container container--narrow">
      <h1 class="page-banner__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <div class="page-banner__intro">
        <p>Dont forget to replace me later!</p>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div class="container container--narrow page-section">

  <?php 
    $theParent = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());
   if ($theParent) { ?>
    <div class="metabox metabox--position-up metabox--with-home-link">
      <p><a class="metabox__blog-home-link" href="<?php echo get_permalink($theParent); ?>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Back to<?php echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></a> <span class="metabox__main"><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
    </div>  
   <?php } 
  ?>

    <?php
    $testArray = get_pages(array(
      'child_of' => get_the_ID()
    )); 

    if ($theParent or $testArray) { ?>
    <div class="page-links">
      <h2 class="page-links__title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($theParent); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></a></h2>
      <ul class="min-list">
        <?php 
          if ($theParent) {
            $findChildrenOf = $theParent;
          } else {
            $findChildrenOf = get_the_ID();

          }

          wp_list_pages(array(
            'title_li' => NULL,
            'child_of' => $findChildrenOf
          ));
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="generic-content">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <?php }

     get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: You don't close your while loop.

Comment: how do i do that properly?

Comment: ? please help? i cant move forward